# Mixed pgfplots, setting domain by calculated xmin

Tags: pgfplots, errors

I am very new to pgfplots and have a (hopefully) short question.
I wanna create a graph with two plots. First one should be created from a text-file (have changed it here to coordinates to make it a little easier) and the second plot should be a function.

The MWE looks like that:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{units}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[width=0.7\linewidth]
%Masse  
\addplot[smooth,blue,solid,ultra thick]
coordinates {
(0, 0)
(1, 1)
(2, 2)
(3, 3)
(10, 10)
};
%lineare Regression
\addplot[smooth,red,dashdotted,thick] 
{1*x};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

It's working fine but now I want to change the the function's domain, depending from the calculated values of xmin and xmax of first plot. 
I thought about something like:

```
\addplot[red,domain=\pgfplots@data@xmin : \pgfplots@data@xmax]
```

or

```
\addplot[red,domain=\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin} : \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax}]
```

But it's not working and I hope for some help from you.

Thnaks and best regards

Comment: Noone have an idea?!?
Even with searching the internet the last days, I haven't found a solution. But I cannot imagine, that nobody else had this problem before... Maybe I'm just too studip to find the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way, though I have to say it's not super elegant. It uses `pgfplotstable`. I start by saving the data to a table. Assuming the data is sorted by x-value, you can extract the smallest x-value with `\pgfplotstablegetelem{0}{x}\of\mydata`, where `x` is the column name, and `\mydata` is the table. I don't know of a way to get the last value in a column though, so I make a new table where the x-values are sorted descending, and get the first x-value of this new table as the maximum.

That said, `pgfplots` can calculate linear regressions for you, which might be of interest, see second `tikzpicture` in code.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{units}

\pgfplotstableread{
x y
0 0
1 1.2
2 1.8
3 3.2
10 9.5
}\mydata
% extract first x-value and save to \TableMin
\pgfplotstablegetelem{0}{x}\of\mydata
\pgfmathsetmacro{\TableMin}{\pgfplotsretval}

% flip table
\pgfplotstablesort[sort cmp={float >}]\mydatainv\mydata
% extract first x-value from flipped table, save to \TableMax
\pgfplotstablegetelem{0}{x}\of\mydatainv
\pgfmathsetmacro{\TableMax}{\pgfplotsretval}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[width=0.7\linewidth]
%Masse  
\addplot+ [ultra thick]
table[x=x,y=y] {\mydata};
%lineare Regression
\addplot[red,dashdotted,thick,domain=\TableMin:\TableMax] 
{1*x};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

% linear regression by pgfplots:
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=0.7\linewidth]
\addplot table[x=x,y=y] \mydata;
\addplot [red,dashed,thick] table[x=x,y={create col/linear regression={y=y}}] \mydata;
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]